# Can´t connect with socket after upgrading from maraidab 10.2.29 -> 10.3.31 in SuSE SLES 12

Tags: sockets, drupal, mariadb, sles

Two weeks ago, SuSE updated the packages for their SuSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) for mariaDB from `10.2.29-3.22.1` to `10.2.31-3.25.1`. This minor update broke the database connections on my SLES 12SP4 production server as well as on my SLES12SP5 development server.

This update introduced a problem with socket connections: Until now I declared the socket in `my.cnf` with 
`socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`for the `[client]` and `[mysqld]` group which was the default location on SLES11 and worked flawlessly.

This behavior changed after the update:  When my drupal php applications now try to connect to this socket they only throw `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away in lock_may_be_available() (`. If I call
`systemctl status mysql.service` it my terminal it informs me that `mysqld[pid]: refused connect from IP`.

Luckily, I figured out that my production machine works with the default `socket = /run/mysql/mysql.sock`. My guess would have been that the new mariaDB version does not accept symlinks as `/var/lib/mysql` is located on a different volume and integrated by symlink in my setup.

But my developement machine refuses this solution as well, I am not able to get the database working again. The major difference between prod and dev is that I already migrated dev to service pack 5, therefore I hesitate upgrading my production environment from SP4 to SP5.

- This is no firewall issue as it does not change after turning off the
  firewall.
- `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` which is also configured in the drupal settings as host
- I changed the socket directory to `/tmp/mysql.sock` as this
  should be reachable from anywhere with no result.
- The file permissions are  `srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 13. Mär 11:59 mysql.sock=`
- `netstat -ln | grep mysql` returns `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTEN         670834 /tmp/mysql.sock`
- `systemctl status mysql.service` returns
  `mariadb.service - MySQL server
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fr 2020-03-13 11:59:54 CET; 3h 2min ago
  Main PID: 12393 (mysqld)
  Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
  Tasks: 30 (limit: 512)
  CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
         └─12393 /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --user=mysql`

There is no evidence of a something concerning the socket handlings in the mariaDB changelog.

Has anybody experienced the same problem? Or any ideas how I could fix this? Unfortunatly, I am no database expert...

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: MariaDB 10.2.31-3.25.1. on SLES starts to use /etc/hosts.allow which is configured different - much more restricted on my dev than on my production server. Therefore the client was not able to reach the database server.

I wonder where this different behavior was introduced - I found nothing in the change logs of mariaDB...